# Excel Power Query crashes within Citrix

Tags: excel, citrix, powerquery

All employees in our organisation work via Citrix clients. On those clients Excel Power Query crashes when loading data from a view on SQL Server (17K rows and about 40 columns). We loaded the data directly to sheet.

In order to investigate the problem I logged in via remote desktop (without Citrix) and it worked without problems. So it is definitely a Citrix problem.
I also saved the results and reopened the file in Citrix without errors. Only getting data from PowerQuery fails within Citrix.

Johan

Comment: Can you send us a crash dump of the Excel process through the built-in "Send a Fown" feature?

1. Edit the registry, open the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting and change the DWORD value ForceQueue to 1
2. Open %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue in Windows Explorer to monitor it
3. Reproduce the crash – at this point something should appear briefly in the ReportQueue folder.

 Sorry about the horrible formatting, it seems like SO doesn't allow it in comments.

Comment: Hi Tristan, I will try. Sorry about my late response.